# Pasar datos a Varias Activitys

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```html
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, paginaprincipal.class);

        String email = etUsuario.getText().toString();
        String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

        if(!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()){
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                String idcliente = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                intent.putExtra("idcliente",idcliente);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(login.this, "Nose pudo iniciar sesion Compruebe los datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.e("FireApp","Error",e);
                        }
                    });
```

> > Quiero pasar el idcliente a otra activity, Al iniciar la sesion (Login) ese inicia paginaprincipal pero tengo otra activity llamado registarcompra,como puedo pasar el idcliente de otra activity pasar registarcompra si que esta se inicie, por decir algo: pasar los datos activity 1 a la activity 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas pasar el id del usuario porque este se puede obtener desde cualquier lado. Simplemente llama `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()`